# What tool is used to uninstall service in Windows 2008?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, services

I could not find the tool InstallUtil.exe to uninstall a service in Windows 2008 Server. Not sure if there is an alternative tool in Win 2008 Server for services?

By the way, I tried to type InstallUtil in cmd console. The app is not available. Normally, as I recall, I use this tool with /u option to uninstall a service:

```
 C:\Program Files(86x)\MyApp\InstallUtil /u myService.exe
```

Not sure where InstallUtil.exe or I have edit my path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sc.exe

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742045(WS.10).aspx

Try `sc delete MyServiceName`.

This doesn't rely on the .NET Framework.

Note that this simply deletes the service from the registry - it doesn't do any cleanup or try to stop the service.

Answer (score 0):

You need the .NET Framework installed on your server for `InstallUtil`.

If you are running this:

```
C:\Program Files(86x)\MyApp\InstallUtil /u myService.exe
```

it will search for `InstallUtil` in the `MyApp` directory. You will need to run it like this:

```
InstallUtil /u "C:\Program Files(86x)\MyApp\myService.exe"
```

note the necessary quotes as well, since `Program Files` has a space in it.

Comment: I think that  the .Net Framework should be part of Windows 2008 server. Otherwise, how other services are installed?

Answer (score 0):

I found this one in Windows 2008 Server. It is in the %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\

Normally, this location is not in the environment path. In order to use this one, I may need to create a SDK similar cmd console with this location added to the console path:

```
 C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\sdkvars.bat""
```

where I need is to copy that bat file to another location and change the path with above location.